# mixed Dirichlet Neumann regularity for an elliptic equation

Tags: elliptic-pde, regularity

Here is a problem which may be easy for some of you but not for me.

**Statement of the problem:**
Denote $\Omega := \{ (x,y) \in (0, \infty) \times (-\infty,\infty) \}$.
Let $f \in L^2(\Omega)$ then by a standard argument we know that there exists a unique $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ satisfying

$u - \Delta u = f \quad \mbox{in} \quad  \Omega$,
$ \quad u = 0 \quad \mbox{dans} \quad x=0, y>0$,
$ \quad \frac{\partial u}{ \partial x} = 0 \quad \mbox{dans} \quad x=0, y<0$.

We also know that for all open subdomain $\mathcal{U} \subset \Omega$, on sait elliptic regularity gives $u \in H^2(\mathcal{U})$.

**Alright, here are my two questions:**
a. what is the regularity of $u$ on the boundary $x = 0$? 
b. do we have $u \in \mathcal{C}(\bar{\Omega})$?

I would very grateful if some can help me.
thanks.

nb: thanks. indeed there was a typo mistake in the rhs.

Comment: I assume f is supposed to make an appearance somewhere in the equations? Grisvard's book is a standard reference for elliptic PDEs in the plane with corner singularities. You are likely to find your answer there.

Comment: Presumably it's $(-\Delta + 1)u=f$, and then we're getting exactly all $u$'s from the domain of $-\Delta$ if $f$ varies over $L^2$.